# ggplot - Getting scale info (has_scale, is_discrete)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm building a function that allows a user to pass a ggplot object and then applies formatting based on other parameters. I need to know what type of scales (discrete/fill/continuous) the plot is using so I know what type of color scheme to apply.

e.g.

```
 p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy, colour = cyl)) + geom_point()
```

`str(p$scales$scales)` gives me a list that looks promising, but much of what shows is functions and I can't work out how to pull details out.

`scale_name` shows `'position_d'` for discrete, `'position_c'` for continuous etc. in the console, but `str(p$scales$scale_name)` returns null

I've tried

```
b <- ggplot_build(p)

b$layout$get_scales() etc
```

but still get functions I can't use

Comment: Please format the code for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy, colour = cyl)) + geom_point()
ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_scales

$x
$x[[1]]
<ScaleContinuousPosition>
  Range:   1.6 --    7
Limits:  1.6 --    7


$y
$y[[1]]
<ScaleContinuousPosition>
  Range:    12 --   44
Limits:   12 --   44
```

Comment: Thanks Hardik, but I can't get that to work. I get 'Error: unexpected '$' in "$"' at the $x.  I have got a bt further and found that class(ggplot_build(p)$plot$scales$scales[[3]])[2] gives me something that's right msot of the time, but not reliable.

Comment: @Matt_B - I ran the code from your code only, it didn't give any error

Comment: Strange, I still get the error if I use your identical code. I tried `ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_scales$x[[1]]`
also, and that returns NULL.
What version of ggplot are you using? I'm on 2.2.1.9000